# Could a active rotational bullet increase accuracy?

Tags: weapons, hard-science, engineering, guns

I don't know where I should ask this, on History, Aerodynamics, Physics or here. But here we go.

So, from what I could see on youtube videos (not the best source, I know), the bullets on rifles and handguns in general spin in order to get a better stabilisation, and thus, a better accuracy.

And so, in order to get that, [the interior of some rifles and pistols barrels are spiral](https://youtu.be/jnYYrdX1F0k). Let's call this type of spinning, a "passive spinning".

Therefore, an "active spinning" would be to add a rocket-like propulsion or a disposable cape in the projectile in order to increase its spin.

The only reason to do this (that I could think of) is to shorten the gun barrel or, in the best case scenario, turn the spiralled barrels unnecessary and make its fabrication process a little bit cheaper.

However, I can't tell if it would be cheaper or more expensive, and since I couldn't find anything related to that, it could mean it doesn't increase accuracy.

Note: Oh, I didn't make it clear, but the bullet wouldn't be self-propelled, just the spinning effect.

Comment: Regarding spinning projectiles with "*rocket-like propulsion*", see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyrojet ; the tl;dr is that it's impractical.

Comment: Oh, I didn't make it clear, but the bullet wouldn't be self-propelled, just the spin.

Comment: @NetoAnanias - under what circumstances would you want to forego the rifled barrel?  Railgun?

Comment: It's advised to wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer in order to give incentive to better ones coming up. Also, you asked for hard science but there is no hard science in the answer you accepted. Please check the tag meanings and consider if necessary to change the requirements of your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The only reason to do this (that I could think of) is to shorten the gun barrel or, in the best case scenario, turn the spiralled barrels unnecessary and make its fabrication process a little bit cheaper.

The costs would increase dramatically, for the following reasons:

- if you want the bullet to auto start its rotation, you either need to [micromachine](https://www.ipqcco.com/wiki/micro-machining) it in a way that air drag forces it to spin (but then you are subtracting kinetic energy which is what makes the bullet effective) or you need to have it propelled. To achieve propulsion you would need to have a shaped nozzle micromachined in the bullet, that would need to withstand the forces involved in the firing. Doable, but not cheap nor cheaper than machining a barrel. Also, you machine a barrel once for no matter how many hundreds or thousands of bullets you will fire. Going on the bullets, you need to machine each one of them.
- again for the autorotation, you would need to be sure that the propulsion from the various nozzles in the bullet is always balanced, else the bullet would deviate from the intended trajectory. You are talking here about burning minuscule amounts of something and ensure that the combustion rates are the same across different chambers and across different bullets, if you want your gunner to not get crazy with guessing how each bullet will behave. Again doable, but at a cost. Oh, and don't forget that the combustible should not react too vividly after the shock of the firing

Comment: Just nickpicking but I have yet to see a barrel that could shoot hundreds of thousands of rounds without being replaced. Usually after a few thousands rounds you'll start noticing a decrease in accuracy. Barrel replacement usually becomes needed in the tens of thousand order of magnitude in military rifles for the generic infantryman (which typically are not pinpoint accurate to begin with).

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, but it would be extremely expensive.

You are essentially firing a small guided rocket. There are experiments and theories about making smart bullets that can rotate or change where they are going, so that snipers could be even more deadly over greater distances.

We haven't mastered it yet, but if you did that you would have an expensive and deadly weapon.

A primitive version of such was once designed called the [gyrojet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyrojet) which often exploded and cost a 100 dollars per round.

Comment: I thought the $100/round was sometime after they quit production?

Answer (score 2):

Its not a good idea.

Something like that was already made, the gyrojet bullet, which were horribly expensive AND inaccurate.  the major problem is rockets are extremely imprecise and the slightest variation in manufacturing of nozzles, propellant burn, or even the presence of dirt caused the rocket thrust to be unbalanced making the bullet less accurate instead of more. Its the reason rockets guidance is so difficult and expensive. If you improved the ballistics by having an initial impulse  like normal bullets you will suffer even more distortion of the rocket nozzles as well as clogging making the problem even worse.

[image]

you can watch test firing [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cJAXpyt8-oQ), and see how it spins.

Comment: Gun Jesus made a video about it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=98c2t_uK5Uo

Answer (score 1):

**Railgun rounds spin via fins.**

[image: railgun round]

https://news.usni.org/2019/01/08/navy-quietly-fires-20-hyper-velocity-projectiles-destroyers-deckgun

You cannot put rifling in a railgun - it has rails.  But it is good to spin the projectile for stability in flight as you lay out.  The projectile has fins to accomplish this, turning some of its ample kinetic energy into rotation.  A projectile like this starts spinning once it leaves the gun.

Other methods to impart spin include spinning the projectile up to speed in advance using an electric motor (which is how some railgun hobbyists do it) or a rotating magnetic field to impart spin while still on the rails.

Comment: Fin-stabilised ammunition is not a new thing, but the fins are to stabilise the projectile without spinning it, not in order to spin it.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 - you are right, of course.  Arrows.   Saturn rockets.  Jarts.   But check it out.  The railgun dart (in these amazing slowmo videos) is spinning.  I think it is from the fins.  https://youtu.be/b72ZWM4c94s?t=73

Answer (score 0):

> Therefore, an "active spinning" would be to add a rocket-like propulsion or a disposable cape in the projectile in order to increase its spin

I take it adding fins to your projectile would be considered 'active' spinning based on your description?

Assuming so, the main reason for taking this approach would be so that you projectile does not have to engage with the rifling of the barrel (but may still do so). There are a number of reasons you would want this, such as either having a stable projectile from a smoothbore barrel, a very light and aerodynamic projectile or having multiple stabilised projectiles fired from each cartridge.

The latter is something the US spent a lot of effort researching as part of the Special Purpose Individual Weapon program- in order to improve the probability of a rifleman hitting a target, one of the approaches was having a number of flechettes (basically fin stabilised darts) fired from each cartridge at a very high velocity. Forgotten weapons did a good video on one of the prototypes [here from 3:00 onwards](https://youtu.be/X1W8iz8DyRw). While the flechettes used in SPIW do (slightly) engage with the barrel rifling to spin, and most other flechettes other flechettes are not spin stabilised I'm sure flechettes could be designed that introduce spin through air resistance on the fins instead of using the rifling, for example.

This could potentially increase the accuracy of an individual flechette (something the SPIW weapons did encounter was issues with the dispersion of flechettes so in principle this could make it a more viable weapon system).

While the accuracy of the actual projectiles are going to be considerably lower due to the dispersion, the practical ability of a rifleman to hit a target could in principle be better using this approach (though historically hasn't really worked out).